# Deploy my own tensorflow model on a virtual machine with AWS

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Tensorflow model which is working perfectly fine on my laptop (Tf 1.8 on OS HighSierra). However, I wanted to scale my operations up and use Amazon's Virtual Machine to run predictions faster. What is the best way to use my saved model and classify images in jpeg format which are stored locally? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options:

1) Start a virtual machine on AWS (known as an Amazon EC2 instance). You can pick from many different instance types, including GPU instances. You'll have full administrative access on this machine, meaning that you can copy you TF model to it and predict just like you would on your own machine.

More details on getting started with EC2 here: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/getting-started/

I would also recommend using the Deep Learning Amazon Machine Image, which bundles all the popular ML/DL tools as well as the NVIDIA environment for GPU training/prediction : https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/

2) If you don't want to manage virtual machines, I'd recommend looking at Amazon SageMaker. You'll be able to import your TF model and to deploy it on fully-managed infrastructure for prediction.

Here's a sample notebook showing you how to bring your own TF model to SageMaker: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_iris_byom/tensorflow_BYOM_iris.ipynb

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will try one of those options! Also one of the things I tried to find out in the AWS documentation is whether I can just load images in jpeg format for inference.